# Symfony2 - Get ID from route to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony

little trouble working something out.  I have a /view-alerts page which displays my data.  For each row of data I provide a delete option

```
<input type="button" value="Delete" data-url="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_delete') }}" onclick="delete_alert( {{ alert[0].id }} )"/>
```

So when this button is clicked, a javascript function is called.

```
function delete_alert(id){
    var answer = confirm("Confirm delete");
    if (answer){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('data-url'),
            data: {row: id},
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                    var splitdata = data.split(":");
                    if(splitdata[0]=="Deleted"){
                        var id = splitdata[1];
                        alert("Your alert has been deleted");
                    }else{
                        alert(data);
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Unknown Error!");
                }
            },
            error:function(){
                alert("Please try again!");
            }
        });
    }
```

So that calls my delete route, and should pass the id of the data row to be deleted.  My route is currently like so

```
NickAlertBundle_delete:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:delete }
    requirements:
       _method:  POST
```

I have the same url pattern as view-alerts because when they delete an alert from this page, I dont want them redirected to another page.

So now I am trying to access the id in my controller so I can delete the alert.  At the moment I am trying

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request)
{
        $id = $request->get('id');

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $alert = $em->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:AvailabilityAlert')->find($id);

        if (!$alert) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Alert not found');
        }

        $alert->setIsDeleted(true);
        $alert->setAlertStatus('Inactive');
        $em->flush();

        return new JsonResponse('Deleted');
}
```

The error I am currently receiving is

> The identifier id is missing for a query of
>   Nick\AlertBundle\Entity\AvailabilityAlert

How can I get the id to my controller with the way I am doing things (through an ajax request?)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried:

```
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest())
                {
                    $id = (int)$request->request->get('row');
    }
```

Instead of:

```
$id = $request->get('id');
```

?

Comment: Why would he want to pull the request from the container when it is already passed in to the controller?  I agree that since the parameter is called 'row' then using row makes more sense than id.

Comment: A good question Cerad. It is just that  I am having the habit of using container.  You are right, I edited.